# Running NonlinearModelFit in more one kernel simultaneously

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting, parallelization, nonlinear, cluster-analysis

I want to perform a nonlinear least square fit of data points upto 3000. Because the model I provide is huge polynomials with 300 to 400 fitting parameters to be estimated, my mac i7 computer proceeds slowly or not at all proceeding. I just like to know if I can run this fitting calculation in multiple processors. My pc has 4 kernels as shown by mathematica. I want to make use of all of them to perform the fitting procedure. But I donot know how to do this. Is there any specific simple mathematica script I can run so that mathematica runs in all of them in reasonable time limit with least memory. I tried to parallelize the NonlinearModelFit command along with its syntax. It says it can not be parallelized and proceeds in sequencential condition. I tried to use ParallelSubmit with NonlinearModelFit and it optimizes only few fitting parameters leaving the other parameters equal to 1.  Can any one tell me how to tackle this problem? I use mathematica 12 version. What about cloud computing. Will this solve the problem. If so, please give me the relevent details.

Regards

Comment: As with any iterative procedure, having good starting values are worth their weight in gold.  It sounds like you're just using the default starting value of 1 for all parameters.  Also, standardizing the predictor variables might help (subtracting the mean and then dividing by the standard deviation is one approach).

Comment: Depending on the structure of your polynomials using `HornerForm` might reduce numerical instabilities.

Comment: If you are really just using big polynomials and nothing else, then LinearModelFit will work. And way faster with a guaranteed minimum too.

Comment: Okay, I take that back. LinearModelFit is way slower for such big polynomials. Sorry for that.

Comment: Some of the variiables are nonlinear. Its actually embedded polynomials of three running variables {u,v,w,E}, meaning that the each polynomial expansion terms itself have sum of few sech functions. My problem is that how to run in many processor simultaneoulsy to reduce computation time like in Fortran or other lannguages. Is there any script to do this? The problem is not with the starting values.

Comment: Maybe it's a semantics thing but the variables can be nonlinear (i.e., `Sech[x1]`) but an equation is "linear" if it is linear in the coefficients associated with the variables.  If your equation is indeed linear, then @JulienKluge 's suggestion to use `LinearModelFit` is still good.

Comment: I am sure that Linear optimization is not possible because a p1 + b p2 where p1 is cc sech(bb(aa-x1)) + ccc sech(bbb(aaa-x1)) + cccc sech(bbbb(aaaa-x1)) and p2 is again something similar to p1 but with different parameters. In this a and b is linear but not other parameters. Do you agree? i used NonlinearModelFit because of this. The (embedded) polynomial I use for my work is in three independent running variables with 200 to 300 parameter together. Do you know how to run mathematica fit making use of all processors in my computer. How to check if it runs in all processors?

Comment: Thanks, that example of `a p1 + b p2` clarifies things.  And so, yes I agree your model is not intrinsically linear. I don't know how to answer your central question as to making use of all processors.  But explaining the structure of your model in the text of your question (rather than in comments) might help as the question is more likely to be read rather than all of the comments.  Also, you do use some non-standard terms such as "independent running variables".  Do you just have 3 predictor variables but maybe 100 functions of those 3 predictor variables?  300 coefficients seems excessive.